# Linux ip route description

Tags: linux, routing

Is it possible to add in the routing table a description for a route?

Something like:

```
ip route add 192.168.10.1/24 via 192.168.1.1 description "route to the example network"
```

I would like when I am running `ip route show` to see these descriptions to be able to manage easier the routing table.

Comment: No - but you can add comments in the files containing the route data (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-* on a nearby RHEL box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like iptables' `-m comment --comment foo`?

Unfortunately not.

Comment: I am afraid that this might be the answer - not implemented, yet.